# How propertly construct fetch promise chain with condition and delay?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

How properly construct fetch promise chain with condition and delay ? I've got

```
fetch("/myApi")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    if (data.foo != "bar")
      return fetch("/setFoo=bar").then(() => delay(100).then(() => {
        if (data.magic != "exist")
          return fetch("/setMagic=exist")
      }))
    if (data.magic != "exist")
      return fetch("/setMagic=exist")
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Great success !"))

function delay(ms) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))}
```

This code should make API request, check is foo value equals bar, if not, set `foo=bar`, than wait 100ms, and then set value `magic=exist` in case it is not set

But in case if `foo` is already `bar` it should immediately set `magic` to `exist`

In my case I duplicated `magic=exist` check and set and it looks all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```js
fetch("/myApi")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(async json => {
    if (data.foo != "bar"){
      await fetch("/setFoo=bar");
      await delay(100);
    }
    if (data.magic != "exist")
      return fetch("/setMagic=exist")
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Great success !"))

function delay(ms) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))}
```

Without `async`

```js
const check = (data) => {
    if (data.magic != "exist")
        return fetch("/setMagic=exist")
}))
}

fetch("/myApi")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        if (data.foo != "bar")
            return fetch("/setFoo=bar").then(() => delay(100).then(() => {
                return check(data)
            }))
        return check(data)
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Great success !"))

function delay(ms) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) }
```

Comment: It seems to fit your requierement. If you don't provide a full running example it's hard to find what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it this way

```js
  fetch("/myApi")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(setIfNotBar)
  .then(setIfMagicNotExist)
  .then(() => console.log("Great success !"))

function delay(ms) { return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) )}
function setIfNotBar(data) { data.foo != "bar" ? fetch("/setFoo=bar").then(delay(100)).then(() => data) : data}
function setIfMagicNotExist(data) { data.magic != "exist" ? fetch("/setMagic=exist"): data}
```